# How to use spread operator in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and I want to use something as Javascript spread operator.

I have followin code:

```
def some_function():
  return {
        'a': "test",
        'b': 1,
        'c': 2
    } 

mapper = some_function()

test = mapper.update({'a': "Updated"})

print(test)
```

The result that I want is:

```
{
   'a': "Updated",
   'b': 1,
   'c': 2
}
```

But I get `None` instead.

Any idea?

Comment: test mapps to the return of mapper.update.

Try to print(mapper) instead

Comment: `mapper` is now updated, see `print(mapper)`. Are you saying you want `test` to have the updated `a` without changing `mapper`?

Comment: @deceze Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: The general design rule in Python is: If a function operates on an already existing object, that object will not be returned. This is called an in-place operation.

Comment: they python doc is your friend https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update it tells `Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return None.` So it updates the object you gave it, it doesnt return you the update.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.update` happens in place so returns `None` so don’t assign the result to a variable.

```
mapper = some_function()
mapper.update({'a': "Updated"})
print(mapper)
#{'a': "Updated", 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Or if you want to keep `mapper` but assign the updated value you can make a new dict using star unpacking:

```
test = {**mapper, 'a': 'Updated'}
```